# When onmouseover, need the large image to change its links to its anchored external sites like the smaller images are

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I have an assignment where the objective is to make sure that the large (changing) image on top also changes links just like its smaller counterpart on the bottom.

I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen. I'm only able to link the larger image with to a single link and not have it change its links to match the links of the smaller images.

Please help (if possible) and please advise if this can be done with just javascript & html/css.

Here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image link assignment</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(imgName, imgFile) {
    document.images[imgName].src=imgFile;
}
function preloadPic() {
    first = new Image();
    second = new Image ();
    third = new Image ();
    fourth = new Image ();
    fifth = new Image ();

    first.src="Philips_radio.png"
    second.src="news.png"
    third.src="jellyfish.png"
    forth.src="saturn.png"
    fifth.src="sport-bike.png"
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="preloadPic()">
<table width="500">
<td colspan="3"><a href="http://www.pandora.com/" target="_blank"><img src="Philips_radio.png" name="bigOne" width="200" height="200"></a></td>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.pandora.com/" target="_blank"><img id="pRadio" name="smallOne1" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','Philips_radio.png')" src="Philips_radio.png" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://news.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="gNews" name="smallOne2" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','news.png')" src="news.png" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://imgur.com/" target="_blank"><img id="imgurJelly" name="smallOne3" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','jellyfish.png')" src="jellyfish.png" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://www.griffithobs.org/sky/skyreport.html" target="_blank"><img id="saturnSkyReport" name="smallOne4" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','saturn.png')" src="saturn.png" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://www.nps.gov/index.html" target="_blank"><img id="roadTripNationalParks" name="smallOne5" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','sport-bike.png')" src="sport-bike.png" height="100px" width="100px"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors does your console give you? One issue I'm noticing is that there's a typo. `forth.src=` should be `fourth.src=`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image link assignment</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(imgName, imgFile, newLink) {
    document.getElementById(imgName).src=imgFile;
    document.getElementById("link").href = newLink;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="500">
<td colspan="3"><a href="http://www.pandora.com/" id="link" target="_blank"><img src="Philips_radio.png" id="bigOne" width="200" height="200"></a></td>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.pandora.com/" target="_blank"><img id="pRadio" name="smallOne1" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','http://i.imgur.com/bE6Jtz1b.jpg', 'http://www.pandora.com/')" src="http://i.imgur.com/bE6Jtz1b.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://news.google.com/" target="_blank"><img id="gNews" name="smallOne2" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','http://i.imgur.com/aopbWb.jpg', 'http://news.google.com')" src="http://i.imgur.com/aopbWb.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://imgur.com/" target="_blank"><img id="imgurJelly" name="smallOne3" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','http://i.imgur.com/beLoPXBb.jpg', 'http://imgur.com/')" src="http://i.imgur.com/beLoPXBb.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://www.griffithobs.org/sky/skyreport.html" target="_blank"><img id="saturnSkyReport" name="smallOne4" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','http://i.imgur.com/lArG2Bob.jpg', 'http://www.griffithobs.org/sky/skyreport.html')" src="http://i.imgur.com/lArG2Bob.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></a></td>

<td><a href="http://www.nps.gov/index.html" target="_blank"><img id="roadTripNationalParks" name="smallOne5" onmouseover="changeImg('bigOne','http://i.imgur.com/cgAPeeqb.jpg', 'http://www.nps.gov/index.html')" src="http://i.imgur.com/cgAPeeqb.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```